# angular 2 http post issue

Tags: php, angular, http-headers, angular2-services

i am getting   error , when i am trying to sent post request to my server 
 how to solve this ?

**error**

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost/posttest.php. Request
>   header field Content-Type is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

**php code**
 http://localhost/posttest.php

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");<br>
$data = array("token"=>"","l_date"=>"");<br>
$data_json = json_encode($data);<br>
echo $data_json;
```

**angular 2 http post code**

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import { Http, RequestOptions,Headers,Response } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'; 

@Injectable()
export class PostsService{
constructor(private http:Http){
    console.log("post service initialized ... ");

}
getPosts(id:number){
    return this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/'+id).map(res=>res.json());
}
postexample(){
    var json=JSON.stringify({milla:"hi",login2:"milla"});
    var param="json="+json;
    let headers1 = new Headers({ 'Accept': 'application/json','Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers1 });
    let body = JSON.stringify(json);
    return this.http.post('http://localhost/posttest.php', body, options ).map((res: Response) => res.json());
}
}
```

Comment: you should also add  allow-headers like this: header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *");

Comment: The browser sends a preflight request with method type as `OPTIONS` to check if the server is allowed to be accessed from different domain. In response to the preflight request if you inject 
 `header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin,Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers");` in your php
 the browser understands that it is ok to make further calls and it will get a valid response to the actual GET/POST call.

Answer (score 0):

in php add the another access control headers:

```
http://localhost/posttest.php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
$data = array("token"=>"","l_date"=>"");
$data_json = json_encode($data);
echo $data_json;
```